# How to prove an inequality (using convexity)

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Say $a,b >0 $ and an integer $p >1$
>
> Prove that $(a+b)^p < 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$

I don't even know how to start, this exercise is on a convexity, concavity and  Taylor practice, so my guess is that it is done with convexity.

Comment: Lookup the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Definition) and its proof by convexity.

Comment: Hint: Write it as $({a + b \over 2})^p \leq {a^p + b^ p \over 2}$.

Comment: You need $a\neq b$ to be strict. Math Induction also should be easy.